# Java JUnit, Interfaces, Class Headings

Tags: java, interface, junit

A programmer has to write a program for an xyz program. He has recognised that both the Div and Add values are based on the same underlying Op data structure. As a result, he has written the following JUnit test code.

```
@Test 
public void testDiv() {
Op aValue = new Div(8, 40, “String”); 
assertEquals(5, aValue.getVal1()); 
assertEquals(“String 40 / 8 = 5”, aValue.toString());
}
```

Based on this code: Write an interface for Op and write the class header for Div.

--
My response is:

```
public interface IDiv {
String aValue();
String toString();
}
```

and

```
public class Div (int, String) {
}
```

is this correct?

Comment: You don't seem the to have the `Op` interface defined. I can only see the `IDiv` interface. Are you sure this is what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My variant is:

```
public interface Op {
    String getVal1();
}
```

and

```
public class Div implements Op {

    public Div(int a, int b, String c) {
        ...
    }

    public getVal1() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't add `toString()` method to `Op` interface because each object in Java implicitly extends `Object` class which already has this method.

Comment: @paradox btw, I've just update my answer: if `Div` implements `Op` then it should provide implementation for all methods from `Op` (`getVal1()` in example).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not a full one. I focused only on technical requirements - that my reasoning is based only on the test code you've pasted. More conclusions could (and probably should) be drown based on the semantics of the classes/objects described there. Let's put it aside for a while.

Your solution doesn't seem to be fully correct (I assume you've meant `Op` as the interface name you posted). Having this definition, the test wouldn't simply compile. We know that whatever implementation of `Op` is passed (here assigned to the `aValue` variable) it has (at least) two methods:

- `getVal1()`
- and `toString()`

The latter is trivial, because every object in Java has this method implemented (`java.lang.Object` a superclass of all classes guarantees that)

So the `Op` interface should look like:

```
/*public*/ interface Op {
    /*some return type*/ getVal1();
    // .. other methods (?)
}
```

The visibility modifier of the `Op` is an issue of low importance here.

The return type of the `getVal1()` method is not obvious. You would have to check it, but probably in order for this line to compile `assertEquals(5, aValue.getVal1());` it needs to be `Integer`, `int` or maybe some smaller numeric types. I am not sure `long` or `Long` would work fit in here.